# Exclude media-type sample from Web API help page

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am newbie in Web API usage, and the problem I'm struggling with problem I can't find solution to.
Common problem is, when instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded media type sample, people get

> Failed to generate the sample for media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. Cannot use formatter 'FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatterTracer' to write type 'Task'.

Common suggestion is to specify own sample in the Config file, but I'm wondering, can I remove this media type help section?

```
config.SetSampleForType("", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), typeof(object));
```

Gives me an empty section.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

- May I ask as to why you would want to remove this section? Like you don't want to support formurlencoded formatter in your service? if yes, then you can remove the formatter itself from the collection of formatters, in which case this section wouldn't show up.

  ```
  config.Formatters.Clear();
  config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
  config.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
  ```
- Alternatively, you can do the following change (highlighed comments) in the file at `Areas\HelpPage\SampleGeneration\HelpPageSampleGenerator.cs` and do the following, which is to filter out the formatters:

  ```
      // Do the sample generation based on formatters only if an action doesn't return an HttpResponseMessage.
      // Here we cannot rely on formatters because we don't know what's in the HttpResponseMessage, it might not even use formatters.
      if (type != null && !typeof(HttpResponseMessage).IsAssignableFrom(type))
      {
          object sampleObject = GetSampleObject(type);

          // Change Begin --------------------------------------
          IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter> filteredFormatters = formatters.Where(frmtr => frmtr.GetType() != typeof(JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter));

          foreach (var formatter in filteredFormatters)
          {

          // Change End --------------------------------------
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You're right, I would like to exclude support of this formatter, because I'm operating with large structured objects and it would be a nightmare to compose them as urlencoded.

Actually, I've tried to remove formatter from the formatters list (my fault, I didn't told that in question), but it doesn't affect section generation.

Comment: I were wrong, I tried to remove formatter like this:
`var formatter = _config.Formatters.FormUrlEncodedFormatter;
_config.Formatters.Remove(format);`
Your code works like expected! Thanks!

Comment: This config variable is a reference to global configuration, would not it affect the other areas of the app?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove specific format type use this code:

```
            var matches = config.Formatters
                            .Where(f => f.SupportedMediaTypes
                                         .Where(m => m.MediaType.ToString() == "application/xml" ||
                                                     m.MediaType.ToString() == "text/xml" ||
                                                     m.MediaType.ToString() == "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

                                         .Count() > 0)
                            .ToList();
        foreach (var match in matches)
            config.Formatters.Remove(match);
```